# Conditional Move on the PowerPC

Tags: assembly, powerpc, machine-code

Is there a conditional-move-equivalent on the PowerPC (32 or 64) instruction set?  It can obviously be emulated using a conditional branch, but I want something that outperforms that.

Answer (score 3):

PowerPC has at least a floating-point conditional move operation, fsel, which works like follows:

```
fsel f0, f1, f2, f3 // f0 = ( f1 >= 0 ? f2 : f3 )
```

For Integer values, you could use bit masks to "select" which value to use.

[Here's a discussion on this topic](http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/2009/01/04/fcmp-conditional-moves-for-branchless-math/) (integer at the bottom)

Comment: Optional instruction, so you should check whether it exists on your target processor ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that PowerPC is RISC, so the instruction set is intentionally simple. You can find useful tips in the IBM "PowerPC Compiler Writer’s Guide" (ISBN 0-9649654-0-2) though - there are a number of examples of branchless implementations of conditional sequences (e.g. max/min) which might give you some ideas.

Also, if you have AltiVec, and your code can be vectorised, then conditional moves are very easy using e.g. compares and `vec_sel`.

Comment: PowerPC is not simple, though; I found ARM much more RISCy, and the "everything can be conditional" aspect is nice. When I was bored and trying to implement fast CRC32 without table-lookup, I found a pipelined combination of "multiply by blah&1" and "AND with -(blah&1)" the fastest - the mul is slow, but fewer instructions, and can run on a different execution unit to the neg+and. Still a bit tedious though.

Answer (score 2):

Using `fsel` by itself can often result in incorrect results for exceptional values like NaN and Inf. You'll have to consider the results for each comparison carefully.

Integer select has been implemented in at least two variants of PowerPC.

IBM has the `selii`,`selir`,`selri`,`selrr` instructions in their AS/400 systems. These can select between a register or a signed 5-bit immediate for each source. The decision is based on an AS/400-specific register.

Motorola/Freescale has the "isel APU" found in the e200 and e500 series (and possibly others). These use a regular condition register bit, but can only select from register sources.